# Python regex with lookbehind and lookahead not working

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python `regex` working finely in [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ep7T2qM-sCizzj7Q):

[image]

However, when I do this in a Python console:

```
import re
rgx = re.compile(r'(?<="careerJobAdsList", ){"jobAds":.*}](?=,"nodes":)')

st = 'widget("careerJobAdsList", {"jobAds":[{"id":607}],"nodes":[{"id":2,"parent_id"'

rgx.match(st)
>>> None
```

I've tried to escape all special characters in `rgx`, but it doesn't change the output.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match` finds match in beginning of string. Use `search` instead

```
print(rgx.search(st))
```

Quoting **[re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)**

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note
>   that this is different from a zero-length match.

*Python Code*

```
import re
rgx = re.compile(r'(?<="careerJobAdsList", ){"jobAds":.*}](?=,"nodes":)')
st = 'widget("careerJobAdsList", {"jobAds":[{"id":607}],"nodes":[{"id":2,"parent_id"'
print(rgx.search(st))
```

Comment: my bad... I always forget that `match` matches only the beginning... Thanks